# React native set view backgroundColor opacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a view that I would like to set the background opacity to 0.5 however I need the text component inside of the view to show completely (as if its opacity was 1)

```
<View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          opacity: 0.5,
          borderRadius: 5,
        }}>
        <Paragraph>folder</Paragraph>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the most straighforward way of reaching this desired outcome is to specify that you want the **backgroundColor** to have this specific opacity, and not the entire View element. Check the 'Opacity' section of this page for more info: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp#:~:text=RGBA%20color%20values%20are%20an,and%201.0%20(fully%20opaque)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp#:%7E:text=RGBA%20color%20values%20are%20an,and%201.0%20(fully%20opaque))

For example, if you want to have a green background, with an opacity of 0.5, you would want to set

```
backgroundColor: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text `folder` to be less opaque, then you will have to apply styling directly to it, while keeping its parent's opacity as desired -

```
<View
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 5,
  }}>
  <Paragraph>
    <span style={{ opacity: 1 }}>
      folder
    </span>
  </Paragraph>
</View>
```

You can also try setting the `backgroundColor` with an opacity attached directly to it -

```
backgroundColor: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```